# Google Cloud Messaging: BroadcastReceiver or Service?

Tags: java, android

What is the generally preferred method of using GCM in its current state?

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#client) only talks about using it with a `BroadcastReceiver` and only mentions `Services` in one sentence without further explanation.

In my application, I need to be able to react to an unknown number of successive GCM messages and queue them so I can process them one by one.  This processing needs to be done in order the messages are received in.

This cannot be done with a `BroadcastReceiver`, as for every broadcast received, a new instance of my receiver class is created (this was the method I tried first as per the getting started guide).  Can it be done with a service or, more precisely, is the instance of my service kept between messages received?

If so, when and how does this service need to be started, added to the manifest, etc.?

I do not need to interact with my main application/UI.  The service can do its business on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM message comes as broadcast so you must use `BroadcastReceiver`. If you need to queue them for any reason. just make your `BroadcastReceiver` hand the message to `IntentService` or anything else you find suitable for your task.

Comment: My essential problem is: how can I get an instance of "something" that persists beyond the invocation of the BroadcastReceiver and what would that "something" be? Also, why does the documentation explicitely mention a service?

Comment: You do not need instance really. `IntentService` should suffice. You can also put your messages in database. But if you really need an instance here, you can go with `Singleton` pattern, or extend your `Application` object of your app

Comment: How would I keep track of my message queue if not in one instance of some class?

Comment: I actually ended up doing it close to what you suggested. My `BroadcastReceiver` now hands the messages to a regular `Service` which then does the processing. The original question if it's possible to use GCM without a `BroadcastReceiver` is still unanswered though?

Comment: It is not possible because GCM messages are broadcasted by OS to your app and to receive broadcast you need BroadcastReceiver